# Running Fedora Directory Server in a VM

Tags: ldap, fedora, virtual-machines

Does anyone have any experience in running Fedora DS in a VM? Are there performance issues? I imagine I/O might be problematic.

We are looking at deploying Fedora DS onto ESX3 virtual machines. While we're planning on loadtesting using SLAMD before going to production I thought I'd ask to see if someone else had any experience with it.

Our current LDAP infrastructure (Sun) is reasonably busy, 500-1000 connections/minute, with >6.5 million operations per day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with all LDAP directories you should be aiming to keep all the DB in RAM, these days even a few million objects is easy, and disk IO is really where the problem usually is with VMs.

Obviously writes have to hit metal, but normally LDAP is over 95% reads, but check your actual op breakdown to confirm.

The other potential issue is the context switch overhead of VMs is much higher so there'll always be a bit more latency then on bare metal.